# Transform UIView into another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to recreate the Google app. I have a `UIImageView` (the Google logo) along with 4 `UIView`s (the 4 colored dots). My goal is to blend the logo into the 4 colored dots as shown below. I'm able to animate the positions properly, but contemplating how to blend the views together.

I was thinking of using something like this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:_googleLogo toView:blueDot duration:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:nil];
```

...but the views don't show up and I want it to be an actual redrawing of the views than just a cross dissolve. What's the best way to achieve this?

[image]

---

For curiosity's sake, check out these mid-animation screencasts:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "and I want it to be an actual redrawing of the views than just a cross dissolve" What does that mean?

Comment: A cross dissolve means that one view's alpha increases while another's decreases. I'm wondering if there's a way to actually transform one view into another, much like a morph effect.

Comment: Well, the thing happening in the screencast you uploaded is not some simple thing that's going to happen by magic: it's a complex animation that you'd have to create completely: some stuff zooms out, other stuff drops into place, etc. That's perfectly doable, but it's not a one-liner. On the other hand, a true "morph", whatever that means, sounds like it would have to be drawn by hand frame by frame.

Comment: I've done all of the animations, zooming, and repositioning using a cross dissolve and resizing the Google logo `UIImageView` to match the frame of the four dots. It looks almost identical to the screencast right now. But does the Google app use a cross dissolve? If you pay close attention, it looks like "Google" is actually transforming into the four dots. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The letters are just replaced by filled circles. The "l" is replaced by a tall ellipse that is then flattened to a circle. It all happens fast, and as part of the movement downward, so there's a good illusion; but there is no "morphing".

Comment: @matt You're right, see edited. That's what I'd like to learn about. What does "replaced by filled circles" entail? Is each letter it's own view? If so, what methods are called to replace them with filled circles?

Comment: I assume that each letter is its own view, because each is clearly animated separately once things go into motion. You can readily use a keyframe animation to replace the content of the layer at the right moment.